# copy files from ubuntu to windows on the same computer

Tags: file-sharing

I have a Dell Inspiron with Windows 10 - I also have a Linux terminal (ubuntu) on the same machine. What is the easiest way to copy files from the Ubuntu terminal to Windows? I am a newbie, and all the ways I have tried failed.

Comment: Go you have a dual-boot or WSL which is what "Linux terminal (Ubuntu)" suggests?

Comment: no, I don't have a dual-boot - just a Linux terminal window to access Ubuntu commands

Comment: https://linuxnightly.com/mount-and-access-hard-drives-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/

Comment: Boot into Windows, run the Windows settings tool (idk what its actual name is), turn OFF the Windows "Fast Boot" option. Back in Linux, run `sudo lsblk -f`. Read `man mount fstab`.